# Assembly counter code won't work or loop forever

Tags: assembly, while-loop, x86, nasm

So, my goal is to make the loop go through x runs and prints msgTrue until the counter is equal to zero. In theory, that should work. I might just have messed up the registers though.

```
comparesCounter:

    cmp ah, 0     ;ah stores the amount of repetitions I want the code to go through
    jne notNull   ;jump if not true  
    jmp exit

notNull:      
    dec ah             ;ah -- 
    mov eax, 4         ;|
    mov ebx, 1         ;|
    mov ecx, msgTrue   ;|>this code prints out what's stored in msgTrue
    mov edx, len1      ;|
    int 80h            ;|

    jmp comparesCounter ;jumps up into counter
```

Should I use other Registers maybe or is the mere concept of my code on level of stupidity beyond help?

Comment: `ah` is part of `eax`. `mov eax,4` sets `ah = 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that modifying `eax` also modifies `ah`. Here's a simple diagram showing the relation between `ah` and `eax`:

```
           eax
--------------------------
|           |     ax      |
|           | ----------- |
|           | | ah | al | |
|           | ----------- |
---------------------------
  3      2      1     0
```

As you can see, `ah` is the most significant half of `ax`, which in turn is the least significant half of `eax`. So when you set `eax = 4`, you're implicitly setting `ah = 0`.

If you want to keep using `ah` for you loop counter, you can place it on the stack temporarily:

```
push eax    ; Save eax's current value on the stack
mov eax, 4
...         
int 80h            
pop eax     ; Restore eax from the stack
```

Comment: Okay, so I just tried that and it doesn't really like it. What's more is I tried to replace AH and CH with eax and ecx and it didn't like THAT either

Comment: When I replace ah and ch with eax and ecx it started endlessly looping...?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. I don't see any use of `ch` in the code you've posted.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes I solved it by adding a counter that counts upwards from 0. Obv the counter is ch. But then I converted them into ECX and EAX and it stopped working/looped foreverr

Comment: Counting down to zero is a better solution, since it removes the need for a `cmp`. You can just do `dec` followed by `jnz`. Anyway, `ch` has the same relation to `ecx` as `ah` does to `eax`. So if you modify `ecx` you modify `ch`, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks! The only problem I have left is that I can't push al onto the stack and I dont know if I can just mov al, eax     push eax     pop eax     mov al, eax

Comment: You cannot push 8-bit registers directly. And `mov al, eax` makes no sense, since `eax` is a larger register than `al`. Just push and pop `eax` like I showed in my answer, and that will take care of `al` and `ah` automatically.